# Why is my animator not saving the animation Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

my animator won't work like wtf,
i'm trying to make an animation in Unity but the animator isn't saving any position or is holding it's original pose when changing transforms
here is my animation timeline from one that works but these are importeded but i wanne make my own
[image]

this is video about the issue:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1163155420618178660/1163156445299232768/2023-10-15_18-47-36.mp4?ex=653e8cda&is=652c17da&hm=cb51ce1d1a93f38ff4ce35f25cc7d84f4be8b884436d583d97d31b9dc548b4a4&

Comment: You arent adding keyframes

Comment: Normally it just automaticly add's them when you record movement

Comment: Is there other stuff over-riding the anim, like code or a built in anim to the model?

Comment: I don't know but i went went the easy route of buying assets for now and hope to find a solution in the future